# Eliminating Sub query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL as below.

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `approveDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `documentNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `INDEX_1` (`documentNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to make a query if a `documentNumber` is approved by all `employeeNumber` or approved by some of `employeeNumber` or not approved by any `employeeNumber`.

I made a query as below.

```
SELECT T1.documentNumber, 
 (CASE WHEN T2.currentNum = '0' THEN '1' WHEN T2.currentNum < T2.totalNum THEN '2' ELSE '3' END) AS approveStatusNumber
FROM myTable AS T1 LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT documentNumber, COUNT(*) AS totalNum, SUM(CASE WHEN approveDate IS NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS currentNum 
    FROM myTable GROUP by documentNumber) AS T2 ON T1.documentNumber = T2.documentNumber 
GROUP BY T1.documentNumber;
```

This SQL works, but very slow.
I tried `explain` on this SQL, the result is as below.

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | T1         | range | INDEX_1       | INDEX_1 | 153     | NULL |   27 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 5517 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | myTable    | index | NULL          | INDEX_1 | 153     | NULL | 5948 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I think I have to eliminate sub query to improve my query.
How can I do the same thing without sub query? Or do I have another way to improve my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression to return `currentNum` could be more succinctly expressed (in MySQL) as

```
  SUM(approveDate IS NOT NULL)
```

And there's no need for an inline view. This will return an equivalent result:

```
SELECT t.documentNumber
     , CASE 
         WHEN SUM(t.approveDate IS NOT NULL) = 0 
           THEN '1'
         WHEN SUM(t.approveDate IS NOT NULL) < COUNT(*)
           THEN '2'
         ELSE '3'
       END AS approveStatusNumber
  FROM myTable t
 GROUP BY t.documentNumber
 ORDER BY t.documentNumber
```